# Users who mentioned each other in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin

We have a smaller example twitter database:

```
user -[TWEETED]-> tweet -[MENTIONED]-> user2
```

and I would like to find out how to write a query in Gremlin, that shows *who were the users who mentioned each other*. I have already read the docs but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: so you would also need a "user2 tweet that mentioned user" to have a scenario where user and user2 mentioned each other, right?

Comment: yes, exactly, but the user tweeted tweet... line only wants to show you the "schema"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this sample data that assume marko and stephen mention each other and marko and daniel mention each other:

```
g = new TinkerGraph()
vMarko = g.addVertex("marko", [type:"user"])
vStephen = g.addVertex("stephen", [type:"user"])
vDaniel = g.addVertex("daniel", [type:"user"])
vTweetm1s = g.addVertex("m1s", [type:"tweet"])
vTweetm2d = g.addVertex("m2d", [type:"tweet"])
vTweets1m = g.addVertex("s1m", [type:"tweet"])
vTweetd1m = g.addVertex("d1m", [type:"tweet"])

vMarko.addEdge("tweeted",vTweetm1s)
vMarko.addEdge("tweeted",vTweetm2d)
vStephen.addEdge("tweeted",vTweets1m)
vDaniel.addEdge("tweeted",vTweetd1m)
vTweetm1s.addEdge("mentioned", vStephen)
vTweetm2d.addEdge("mentioned", vDaniel)
vTweets1m.addEdge("mentioned", vMarko)
vTweetd1m.addEdge("mentioned", vMarko)
```

you could handle it with the following:

```
gremlin> g.V.has("type","user").as('s')
            .out("tweeted").out("mentioned").as('m').out("tweeted")
            .out("mentioned").as('e').select.filter{it[0]==it[2]}       
==>[s:v[daniel], m:v[marko], e:v[daniel]]
==>[s:v[stephen], m:v[marko], e:v[stephen]]
==>[s:v[marko], m:v[stephen], e:v[marko]]
==>[s:v[marko], m:v[daniel], e:v[marko]]
```

This approach uses `select` to extract the data from the labelled steps then a final `filter` to find those where "s" (vertex in the first position) is equal to the "e" (vertex in the final position).  This of course means that there is cycle pattern detected where the one user mentioned another and the other mentioned that person back at some point.

If you follow that much then we can clean up the result a little bit so as to get the unique set of pairs:

```
gremlin> g.V.has("type","user").as('s')
            .out("tweeted").out("mentioned").as('m')
            .out("tweeted").out("mentioned").as('e')
            .select.filter{it[0]==it[2]}
            .transform{[it[0].id,it[1].id] as Set}.toList() as Set
==>[daniel, marko]
==>[stephen, marko]
```

By adding a `transform` to the previous code, we can convert the result to "id" (the user's name in this case) and flip everything to `Set` so as to get unique pairs of results.

Comment: one more "extra": what if we only need those, who do not KNOW each other? in SQL this would be something like "not in" or "minus"

Comment: do you mean, someone who mentioned someone who never mentioned them back?

Comment: I mean "adding another relation" to the schema, like:
user1 -Knows-> user2

and using this I would like to add the restriction that
- user1 mentioned user 2 and vice-versa
- user1 does not know user 2 and vice-versa

Comment: maybe just extend the `filter` after the `select` to check the "knows" edge.  `.filter{it[0]==it[2] && !it[0].both('knows').retain([it[1]]).hasNext()}`